# Input being hidden after focus on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, focus, blur

I have an input that appears and gains focus after a button is clicked. The issue is that, on a mobile browser only, after the input gains focus it receives a `blur` event and the touch keyboard hides. On a desktop browser the blur event doesn't even get received after it receives focus.

I'v tried to call `preventDefault` on the `blur` event but the problem is that doesn't help when I want the user to dismiss the input by clicking outside of it.

This is the code that show the input:

```
$('#searchbar-form').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
                $('#container-main-search').addClass('search-expanded');
            });
```

the input inside `#container-main-search` has `autofocus`. This is the input code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control searchbar-input" id="searchbar-input" role="searchbox" name="name" autofocus>
```

Comment: Please provide some of code.

Comment: @hkg328 I just put some, but I think is not very helpful, I don't know how to put some more details without giving you the entire page code.